# iOS:UIWebView showing view in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I'm creating UIWebView programmatically and loading url in the UIWebView. But the problem is I have tableview in the background and the table view it shows:

[image]
As you can see you can see the lines of the tableview in the background.

I tried to change the background color:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.opaque = YES;
```

But it didn't change a thing.

Here is how I'm loading the UIWebView:

```
 // MywebView is subclass of UIWebView
 -(void)loadWebView
{
    self.web = [[MywebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.web];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.web];
    self.web.MywebViewdelegate = self;

}
```

Any of you knows why is showing the tableview in the background?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like the table view is on top? Try `parent.bringSubviewToFront(yourWebView)`

Comment: Are you able to tap on textfield or button in the page?

Comment: @hola, I bring UIWebView.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever, Yes, I'm able to tap on the textfield and button of the page.

Comment: Why don't you show us your view controller so we can understand the view hierarchy better?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever, I have updated my post

Comment: @user2924482 what does `MywebView` class look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Instrumentation to find the hierarchy of view in your application. Most probably yourTableView in on top.
Use [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview] and [self.view sendSubviewToBack:webview] to bringing webview to front and back respectively.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what exactly MyWebView class is implemented. But I ma pretty sure to inform you that the background will be okay if you do this

```
- (void)loadWebView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.web = [[MywebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [view addSubview:self.web];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
   self.web.MywebViewdelegate = self;
}
```